# Tile collision bug in HTML5 JS Canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm a beginner at game development and have been struggling with getting collision done right between an array of tiles and a player rectangle. This game features jumping and gravity. First of all the collision works, but is very clunky. Sometimes when the player ends up on top of a tile and a little to the edge, it will instantly teleport to either the right or left side (depending on what edge/corner) and fall of it. This also happens when colliding with the bottom of the tile; the player will instantly teleport to the side and go up further.
From what I understand the tile collision detector confuses the collision with one or the other side because when the player hits the edge of a tile the detector reads it as if it collided with both and decides to place the player elsewhere base on the highest coordinate velocity (aka speedX and speedY). I figured this out by setting speedY = 0 every time it hits the top of a tile, which fixed the issue, but another one came out of it. Now, if the player is on top of a tile and then falls of and shortly strafe back, it doesn't collide with the tile's side, but it rather quickly goes back on top of it again.

I just need some tips on how i should resolve this, because everything I try leads to another problem. I've heard this is a common bug among developing 2D tile based games.

Here is my code for the collision detection (the array for the tile map is 2D):

```
function TileCollisionManager() {
let tileSize = 32;
let baseCol = Math.floor(player.x/tileSize);
let baseRow = Math.floor(player.y/tileSize);
let colOverlap = player.x%tileSize;
let rowOverlap = player.y%tileSize;



//horizontal collision detection

if (player.speedX > 0) {
    if ((fglayer[baseRow][baseCol+1] && !fglayer[baseRow][baseCol]) ||
        (fglayer[baseRow+1][baseCol+1] && !fglayer[baseRow+1][baseCol] && rowOverlap)) {
        player.x = baseCol*tileSize;
    }
}

if (player.speedX < 0){
    if((!fglayer[baseRow][baseCol+1] && fglayer[baseRow][baseCol]) ||
        (!fglayer[baseRow+1][baseCol+1] && fglayer[baseRow+1][baseCol] && rowOverlap)){
        player.x = (baseCol+1)*tileSize;


    }
}

//vertical collision detection

//Collision with the top of a tile
if(player.speedY>0){
    if ((fglayer[baseRow+1][baseCol] && !fglayer[baseRow][baseCol]) ||
        (fglayer[baseRow+1][baseCol+1] && !fglayer[baseRow][baseCol+1] && colOverlap)) {
        player.y = ((baseRow)*tileSize);
        player.jumping = false;
        player.speedY = 0;
        player.gravity = 0;
        onGround = true;
    } else {
        onGround = false;
    }
}

 //Collision with the bottom of a tile
if (player.speedY<0) {
    if ((!fglayer[baseRow+1][baseCol] && fglayer[baseRow][baseCol]) ||
        (!fglayer[baseRow+1][baseCol+1] && fglayer[baseRow][baseCol+1] && colOverlap)){
        player.y = (baseRow+1)*tileSize;
    }
}
```

If I'm too unclear please speak out. Thanks in advance!
EDIT: the variable fglayer is a reference to the tilemap array.

Comment: Not enough information to work out the problem.  Could be that if the player is moving in both x and y then the `speedX  < 0` test passes you update the player position. `player.x = (baseCol+1)*tileSize;` but that means for the y tests you are using the wrong value for `baseCol` and if either speedX test changes the position you have the wrong `colOverlap` for the y tests. But this is just a guess as there is not enough code to test it on. And yes collision testing is hard, using pen and paper to systematically visualize all possibilities will help if it gets too complex.

Comment: How much more information is needed?
Thanks for replying.

Comment: Hard to say as the reason for the unwanted behaviour is unknown.  Enough to reproduce the problem in runnable form.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Here is a jsfiddle I've made with the code in action enough to run the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/8121u356/